# WHERE clause based on user-defined

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, where-clause

I have a variable, `date_order`, which I define within the SELECT clause,

`rank() over (partition by a.mother order by to_char(a.from_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy') desc) as date_order`.

I wish to include only the observations with `date_order=1`.

However, if I include the condition, `date_order=1`, to the WHERE clause in the statement below, `and date_order=1`, I obtain an error. My questions in this regard are:

1. Is it possible to condition on `date_order`, defined within the SELECT clause? If yes, how do I do this properly?
2. If it is not possible, do you have a suggestion for how I should proceed instead?

I use the following code:

```
select to_char(a.from_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy') as fromdate, a.mother, a.mother_NAME,a.mother_GROUP, a.child_WEIGHT,
a.NODE_NO, a.NODE_NO_PARENT,
rank() over (partition by a.mother order by to_char(a.from_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy') desc) as date_order
,c.child_WEIGHT as PARENT_child_WEIGHT
from table_a a
left join table_b b
on a.mother_ref=b.mot_ref
left join table_c c
on a.NODE_NO_PARENT=c.NODE_NO and a.mother=c.mother
where 1=1
and a. NODE_TYPE in ('Model mother') 
and  a.child_WEIGHT <> 0
and  c.child_WEIGHT <> 0 
;
```

Thank you in advance. Feel free to correct me if my use of SQL syntax is wrong, but please bear in mind that this is only my third time using SQL.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use select over select.

```
select * from (
select to_char(a.from_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy') as fromdate, a.mother, a.mother_NAME,a.mother_GROUP, a.child_WEIGHT,
a.NODE_NO, a.NODE_NO_PARENT,
rank() over (partition by a.mother order by to_char(a.from_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy') desc) as date_order
,c.child_WEIGHT as PARENT_child_WEIGHT
from table_a a
left join table_b b
on a.mother_ref=b.mot_ref
left join table_c c
on a.NODE_NO_PARENT=c.NODE_NO and a.mother=c.mother
where 1=1
and a. NODE_TYPE in ('Model mother') 
and  a.child_WEIGHT <> 0
and  c.child_WEIGHT <> 0
)t
where t.date_order = 1
```

As I know you cannot use alias (in your case date_order), in WHERE block at the same SELECT statment

Answer (score 0):

Put that into some CTE (see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/with.html), and then you will be able to filter against `date_order` column.

It could look like something like this:

```sql
WITH cte as
(
    select 
            to_char(a.from_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy') as fromdate, a.mother, a.mother_NAME,a.mother_GROUP, a.child_WEIGHT,
            a.NODE_NO, a.NODE_NO_PARENT,
            rank() over (partition by a.mother order by to_char(a.from_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy') desc) as date_order
            ,c.child_WEIGHT as PARENT_child_WEIGHT
    from table_a a
    left join table_b b on a.mother_ref=b.mot_ref
    left join table_c c on a.NODE_NO_PARENT=c.NODE_NO and a.mother=c.mother
    where 1=1
    and a. NODE_TYPE in ('Model mother') 
    and a.child_WEIGHT <> 0
    and c.child_WEIGHT <> 0 
)
select * from cte
where date_order = 1;
```